# Why do shareholders allow CEOs and other executives to have extraordinarily high salaries compared to regular managers and non-managerial employees?

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, labor-economics, human-capital, income-distribution

The [wage gap between CEOs and employees](https://www.statista.com/statistics/424159/pay-gap-between-ceos-and-average-workers-in-world-by-country/) varies from country to country. A 2021 article from  [CNBC discussed how CEOs](https://www.cnbc.com/2021/09/15/in-2020-top-ceos-earned-351-times-more-than-the-typical-worker.html) in the US on average earned 351 times more than the average US employee. The article also says that according to the Economic Policy Institute CEO's salaries have grown by 1322% since 1978.

Why does such a wage gap variation exist?

I understand that some CEOs are the founders of their own companies, but are the majority of CEOs the founders of the companies they work for? And can this explain why their salaries are so enormous? Or can the huge wage gap between CEOs and other employees be explained by CEOs having either direct or indirect control over their salaries even when they're not the founders of the companies they work for and don't own any voting shares such as [class B shares](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/classbshares.asp)?

Why don't most multinational companies and conglomerates attempt to minimize the salaries of their CEOs other than by offering shares as compensation instead of higher monthly salaries?  It seems that companies around the world limit the salaries of non-executive and non-managerial employees to a far greater extent than they limit the salaries of executive and managerial employees.

Why don't these corporations attempt to minimize the total compensation that their CEOs receive including the number of company shares they compensate their CEOs with?

Are CEOs in control of the finance and human resource departments i.e. the departments that control or dictate employee compensation?

Comment: There's like 5 different questions here.